# nth level differences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a *sequence* of numbers, I am calculating the **difference** between the numbers until I am left with a **single integer**.

```
2     1     3     4     3
   1    -2    -1     1    | level 1 differences
      3    -1    -2       | level 2 differences
         4     1          | level 3 differences
            5             | level 4 differences
```

I aim to get:

1. number of levels
2. final single integer difference

**I am looking for a better way to approach this, since my list has thousands of numbers, thus, has a lot of levels.**

Is there a better mathematical approach to this, rather than using the old school way for *quadratic* or *cubic* sequences?

Comment: The keyword for this process is "divided differences"

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, just what I was looking for. I got it on a basic level.

Comment: The number of levels is just the number of items in the highest level minus 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate the differences for a few iterations on a generic sequence, you get
$$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
a_0&&a_1&&a_2&&a_3\\
&a_1 - a_0&&a_2 - a_1&&a_3 - a_2\\
&&a_2 - 2a_1 + a_0&&a_3 - 2a_2 + a_1\\
&&&a_3 - 3a_2 + 3a_1 - a_0
\end{array}$$

You might be able to spot the pattern forming here. In general $$f(a_0,\dots,a_n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}\binom nka_k$$
Where $f$ is your final single difference.

The binomial coefficients have this property:

$$\binom n0 = 1, \binom nk = \frac{n - k+1}k\binom n{k-1}$$
which allows you to easily calculate the correct coefficient for each term as you go along. Note that despite the divisions, the binomial coefficient is always an integer.

Assuming you are using a 0-based array, this makes a convenient algorithm:

```
function Difference(array[]) 
{
    n = length(array) - 1
    coef = 1
    if(n is odd) coef = -1
    k = 0      //regardless of the type of your values, n, coef, k should all be integers
    d = 0      //d is of the same type as your values
    while(k <= n)
    {       
        d = d + coef * array[k]
        k = k + 1
        coef = -(n - k + 1) * coef / k
    }
    return d
}
```